# c programming store string into a char array

Tags: c, arrays

Hi i am trying to store a sentence into a char array so that i can use it later easily. My first prinf is able to print out nicely so i wan to save that format into a char array as there is no string functions. But my second printf is not reading the data from country.

```
char* str1;
printf("\n%s Capital\t\t: %s\n", country1, getCapital(country1));
str1 = "\n%s Capital\t\t: %s\n", country1, getCapital(country1);
printf("\n%s", str1);
```

Any ways to store a sentence into a char array? Thanks

Comment: what is `str1 = "\n%s Capital\t\t: %s\n", country1, getCapital(country1);` this is not the correct format.

Comment: @Himanshu I'm guessing bash? :D

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense. You cannot randomly guess the C language syntax, you actually have to know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to read from files, try this:

```
#include "mbed.h" 
int main() {
    char buffer[64];
    char *response = "simple beta test";
    sprintf(buffer, "This is a %s ", response);
    printf("Response=%s\r\n", buffer);
}
```

Comment: I suggest [snprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf), a safe version of `sprintf` that doesn't suffer from buffer overruns.

Comment: And why the `\r` in `printf("Response=%s\r\n", buffer);`?

Comment: mbed.h ? What's that?

Answer (score 1):

Make `str1` an *array* big enough to contain all the text, and then use [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to format the string into the array.